# Union of big SQL queries vs multiple database calls and merging in the application

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently we have two batch jobs which fetch different information but functionally related.

Say Job1 fetches details D1 and D2 
    Job 2 fetches D3 
 
We are going to merge these two jobs in to one, such that it retrieves D1, D2 and D3 and writes to a single file.

One challenge related to performance in merging is that D1 contains most of the information from D3. In merged job we want to exclude the D3 information while fetching D1. I am considering the below options. Please advise which one is better or is there a better alternative.

1. Merging the data in the application. 
    
   1.1 Application executes query for D3 information and stores key values in a Set 
   1.2 Application executes query for D1 and D2  
   1.3 While writing D1 information into file, it will check the map and excludes if it exists.
2. Use SQL UNION and create a single query

   fetch D1, D2 where key not in (fetch All keys for D3) 
    
   UNION 
    
   fetch D3

Which one will be efficient considering huge tables and joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any performance issue, you should test the different approaches to see what works in your environment.

My bias is to do all the work in the database.  The database can marshall more resources for this type of work:

```
with d1 as (. . .),
     d2 as (. . .),
     d3 as (. . .)
select d3.*
from d3
union all
select d1.*
from d1
where not exists (select 1 from d3 where d1.key = d3.key)
union all
select d2.*
from d2
where not exists (select 1 from d3 where d2.key = d3.key);
```

This assumes there are no duplicates within each data source and not between `d1` and `d2`.